How to add a concave border at bottom of an html element?
I am trying to build a clone of Netflix's home page to hone my web desiging skills. Netflix's home page has a concave border at the bottom of hero section. I have added a straight line border at the bottom of my netflix-clone home page. I want to make it a concave border mimicking the real Netflix home page. Here are the images of my desired outcome (real Netflix homepage) and so far achieved design (netflix clone homepage). Thanks in advance. 
I added a straight line border at the bottom of my hero section but I would like to add a concave border in its place at the bottom of my hero section instead.

https://css-shape.com/curved-edge/

Maybe Netflix can tell you：
enter image description here
.default-ltr-cache-1f97ztc {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        position: absolute;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        margin: auto;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        border: solid .25rem transparent;
        border-top-left-radius: 50% 100%;
        border-top-right-radius: 50% 100%;
        border-bottom: none;
        background: radial-gradient(50% 500% at 50% -420%, rgba(64, 97, 231, 0.4) 80%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%), black;
        -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
        background-clip: padding-box;
    }

    .default-ltr-cache-1f97ztc:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        margin-top: -.25rem;
        border-radius: inherit;
        background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(33, 13, 22, 1) 16%, rgba(184, 40, 105, 1), rgba(229, 9, 20, 1), rgba(184, 40, 105, 1), rgba(33, 13, 22, 1) 84%);
    }

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>demo</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="default-ltr-cache-1f97ztc">
        
    </div>

</body>
</html>

